# tkinter, python, Remove names from the list while in the program

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I have trouble with removing unnecessary names from the list when I turn on the program,
Wants to remove names from the list with the program enabled

```
import random
import tkinter, sys
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox


list = ['Kamil Winnicki', 'Wiktor Jasiński', 'Adam Turowski', 'Arek Major', 'Dominik Piechotka', 'Jakub Laskowski', 'Jakub Materak', 'Kacper Kołodziejski', 'Kamil Stankiewicz', 'Konrad Nosek', 'Krzysiek Wawszczak', 'Andrzej Oplebsiak', 'Miłosz Tarucin', 'Paweł Pawłowski', 'Mateusz Lebioda']

def koniec():
    sys.exit()

def losowanie():
    messagebox.showinfo(message=random.choice(list))

main = tkinter.Tk()

#nagłowek
te = tkinter.Label(main, text = 'Lista 1T:')
te.pack()

#Wyswietla liste 1T
listbox = Listbox(main)
listbox.insert(1, '1. Mateusz Lebioda', '2. Jakub Laskowski', '3. Kamil Winnicki', '4. Wiktor Jasiński', '5. Adam Turowski', '6. Arek Major', '7. Dominik Piechotka', '8. Jakub Materak', '9. Kacper Kołodziejski', '10. Kamil Stankiewicz', '11. Konrad Nosek', '12. Krzysiek Wawszczak', '13. Andrzej Oplebsiak', '14. Miłosz Tarucin', '15. Paweł Pawłowski')
listbox.pack()
#losuje
y = tkinter.Button(main, text = 'losuj', command = losowanie)
y.pack()

#wyjscie z aplikacji
x = tkinter.Button(main, text = 'Zakoncz', command = koniec)
x.pack()

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean, which list do you want to remove entries from, list, or listbox. How do you want to remove them, via a button? What have you already tried?

Comment: I want to remove the name from the list and the listbox, by the button that removes the name and decreases the name pool for the draw

Comment: Have you read the documentation on the `Listbox` widget? The methods for deleting items is documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Be more clear**

I've somewhat understood what your problem was. I guess you want to delete items from listbox on the click of a button('delete' is the button here)
I've made some changes:

1) It's not sys.exit() to close the window you must use main.destroy() where main is from

> main = tkinter.TK()

2) Use listbox.delete(0,END) to delete entire listbox items

3) Then the list comprehension creates a list of items in name_list which are not present in unnecessary_names( List of names you want to remove!)

> final_list = [x for x in name_list if x not in unnecessary_names]

4) Update the listbox using listbox.insert(END,item) for every **item** in final_list. 
 **NOTE:** END is a special parameter to **insert** method to specify to add items after the end of the list.

```
import random
import tkinter, sys
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox


unnecessary_names = ['apple', 'pineapple', 'lemon']
name_list = ['pineapple', 'apple', 'tomato' ,'onion','egg']    
def end():
    main.destroy()

def draw():
    messagebox.showinfo(message=random.choice(unnecessary_names))
def delete():
    listbox.delete(0,END)
    final_list = [x for x in name_list if x not in unnecessary_names]
    for item in final_list:
        listbox.insert(END,item)



main = tkinter.Tk()

#heading
te = tkinter.Label(main, text = 'Lista 1T:')
te.pack()

#Displays a 1T list
listbox = Listbox(main)
for items in name_list:
    listbox.insert(END,items)
listbox.pack()

#delete
z = tkinter.Button(main, text = 'delete', command = delete)
z.pack()
#draw
y = tkinter.Button(main, text = 'draw', command = draw)
y.pack()

#exit
x = tkinter.Button(main, text = 'end', command = end)
x.pack()

main.mainloop()
```

And finally I don't understand polish so had to translate it.

**Enjoy programming**

In polish:

**Cieszyć się programowaniem**